# How to hold plot figures in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

I have this code, where c_X,c_Y,c_Z,X,Y,Z X_2,Y_2,Z_2,X_4,Y_4,Z_4, are lists of points (my data).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

for i in range (2):

    fig = plt.figure(i)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    ax.scatter(c_X,c_Y,c_Z, color = 'midnightblue')
    ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, color = 'mediumaquamarine')
    ax.scatter(X_2,Y_2,Z_2, color = 'cadetblue')
    ax.scatter(X_4,Y_4,Z_4, color = 'cadetblue')
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_zlabel('z')
    plt.draw()
```

How can i hold or get the 3 plots, in 3 different figures, in the end ?

Comment: Try reducing the indentation of the `plt.draw()` one level, and possibly change it by `plt.plot()`

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code as suggested in the comments to your question.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

for i in range (2):

    fig = plt.figure(i)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    ax.scatter(c_X,c_Y,c_Z, color = 'midnightblue')
    ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, color = 'mediumaquamarine')
    ax.scatter(X_2,Y_2,Z_2, color = 'cadetblue')
    ax.scatter(X_4,Y_4,Z_4, color = 'cadetblue')
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()
```

I think this does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 4 figures you can just use:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(c_X,c_Y,c_Z, color = 'midnightblue')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, color = 'mediumaquamarine')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(X_2,Y_2,Z_2, color = 'cadetblue')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(X_4,Y_4,Z_4, color = 'cadetblue')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()
```

Is that working?

Or you can merge your arrays into one for X, one for Y and one for Z. Create a list for the color and use a loop:

```
c = ['color1', 'color2', etc]

for i in range(k):
    plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)
    ax.scatter(X[i], Y[i], Z[i], color=c[i])
    plt.show()
```

Comment: That's not exactly what i wanted to reproduce. I want those lists together in one graph and i already have them. The problem is that i basically want to repeat the graph with all those points of all the lists 3 times.